# Bind LINQ Query results to Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datalist

I have a query like this

```
 var businessList = (from u in _DB.Users
join cat in _DB.BusinessCategories on u.UserId equals cat.UserId
select new BusinessDetails(u.Businesses.FirstOrDefault(), u)).Skip(0).Take(10);

dlBusiness.DataSource = businessList.ToList();
dlBusiness.DataBind();
```

I have Businessname as a member of the Business class . I have a DataList as below

```
 <asp:DataList ID="dlBusiness" DataKeyField="UserId" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
            <%#Eval("Business.BusinessName")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:DataList>
```

Here is class defination

```
public class BusinessDetails
    {

        public BusinessDetails(Business business,User user){
            this._Business = business;
            this._UserDetails = user;

        }

        private string _distance;
        public string Distance
        {
            get { return _distance; }
            set { _distance = value; }
        }

        private Business _Business;
        public Business BusinessData
        {
            get { return _Business; }
            set { _Business = value; }
        }
        private User _UserDetails;

        public User UserDetails
        {
            get { return _UserDetails; }
            set { _UserDetails = value; }
        }


    }
```

But this displays blank? How can I bind it to the DataList ?

Comment: can you add in the definition of the BusinessDetails class? Does it have a Business property?

Comment: Remove `DataKeyField="UserId"` and try then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change it to

```
DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BusinessData.BusinessName")
```

presuming that the business class has a `BusinessName` property?

Comment: ok first port of call is there a business property? Secondly is the list non empty?

Comment: If I have a for loop after the query I can see all business names with Response.Write(detail.BusinessData.BusinessName + "<br/>");

Comment: Try either exposing a Businessname prop on the BusinessDetails class that does the BusinessData.BusinessName call in code so you can check it or casting container.dataitem to the BusinessDetails type

Comment: How about other properties ?I have about 150 columns . Shouldn't it work without exposing all those ?

Comment: Cool.Works now. It was my fault that I changed query after I posted  and it was not working cause I was not passing right parameter .Now one more question I have is does it execute query at point until i execute tolist ? I need to get total count for paging purpose if you can help.Thanks.

Comment: @Sonesh Dabhi The query executes when you iterate through the collection or when you call an "eager" operator like `ToList` on it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted

`<%#Eval("BusinessData.BusinessName")%>`

instead of

`<%#Eval("Business.BusinessName")%>`

in the `ItemTemplate` tag.

I don't think you have a UserId field on the `BusinessDetails` class. 
You should replace that with an unique key column name or remove it. I saw that you can access the `BussinessName` so the access specifier is public.

The binding is correct. If the dataList control `dlBusiness` can't find that property an exception is thrown. 
Maybe the cause of the problem comes from the fact that the `businessList` returns an empty BussinessName.